# enable cookies and javascript

Tags: javascript, paypal, jmeter

I am trying to checkout using PayPal in sandbox environment in my script in JMeter.

It throws an error in the response tree as were sorry, but to checkout using PayPal, you need to turn on javascript and enable cookies in your web browsers settings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344112/jmeter-and-javascript

Comment: Please ask a concrete and repeatable question. Show what you did so far. Use proper tags

Answer (score 0):

Load testing PayPal is not the best idea, I would recommend leaving it to PayPal QA engineers and focus solely on your application. Even if you figure out that PayPal operations are slow - I don't think you will be able to do anything with it.

In regards to your question itself: well-behaved JMeter test must represent a real user using real browser as close as possible with all related stuff (cookies, headers, cache, think times, etc.). So first of all add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan.

Also be aware that according to [JMeter main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does

So if the application you're testing is built using [AJAX technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) don't expect JMeter to create and send JavaScript-driven requests, you will need to add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to mimic them.

Check out [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article for more tips and tricks