# How to handle JavaScript files via Jmeter

Tags: javascript, html, jmeter

I get this message in Jmeter when I run my testplan.

```
<noscript>
    <p>
        <strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript,
                you must press the Continue button once to proceed.
    </p>
</noscript>
```

How do I get around this issue on JMeter?  When I go to the link manually in Chrome, the page/charts load fine.

I asked the UI engineer how things worked and they said when we go to the webpage

1. The http request returns an html
2. The browser reads the html and requests js files.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @Barmar, there's no code.  this is from the jmeter app with all the controllers and things.  i can try to copy/paste the jmx file in here if that will help.

Comment: Looks like I found my answer; JMeter doesn't interpret JS in downloaded pgs  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344112/jmeter-and-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JMeter Project](http://jmeter.apache.org/) main page:

> **JMeter is not a browser**
>
> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

Browsers don't do any magic, they just execute [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) and render responses. If JavaScript is being used to "draw" something on page - you should not be interested in it as it happens solely on client side.

If JavaScript is used for building i.e. [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) requests - these are basically "normal" HTTP Requests which can be recorded using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and replayed via [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

If you cannot successfully replay your script - most likely you're missing [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) and/or need to perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) of dynamic parameter(s)